# Twitter Bootstrap Submit Button Placement Not Behaving

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using a default/vertical form, the [bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) suggests that the submit button sits underneath the various inputs but that's not the case [in my form.](http://anjunatl.com/stack/bootstrap-submit-button-placement.html)

When the browser has a large viewing space, it sits beside the last input field and is not in line. If you resize the browser to a phone or tablet width, Responsive takes over and it displays correctly.

Changing the wrapping div from `.span12` to `.span3` pushes the button down, but it seems like a hackish fix because adding `.span3` to the inputs and buttons to make them uniform in size [yields the button pushed off to the side.](http://anjunatl.com/stack/bootstrap-submit-button-placement-spans.html)

Am I missing some markup or is there an issue with Bootstrap? In their docs, the button is preceded by a checkbox label and some help text wrapped in a `p` - so that could be affecting their styling to make it look correct.

Comment: To have the button placed correctly beside the input box, I think you have to add the class `form-inline` to the form. Now, you have to boxes on top of each other, and I'm not quite sure you can have it both ways with the default bootstrap.css

Comment: I'm looking to have the submit button be below the last input box. Thanks for that info though.

Comment: Oh, sorry – I thought you wanted the button as it is – but aligned verticaly with the textbox. Check my answer =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put your submit button in a div with the class `controls`.

[image: button on div.controls]

If you check the source on the Bootstrap documentation page, they even divide all the inputs and buttons in `control-group`s and `controls`.

Comment: Awesome. The funky thing with `control-group` is it has a lot of margin on it - I think it's only meant to be used in `.form-horizontal`.

Comment: Might be... The Twitter Bootstrap requires you to do as they wish, guess that's why it's called a framework =)

Comment: Yeah. Its nuances can be pretty frustrating at times. Speaking of, I just realized why the button placement is off after you specify a span [in the now-patched-with-your-fix example](http://anjunatl.com/stack/bootstrap-submit-button-fixed-spans.html)... yet another nuance - Responsive adds margin to any span on larger displays. Bleh.

Comment: @anjunatl `.controls` should work fine in most situations, but the framework suggests the `.form-actions` class.